# How to change values of pandas dataframe based on the first row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
dir

buy
buy
buy
buy
```

I want that if the value of the first row is "buy", so do this:

```
dir

buy
sell
buy
sell
```

If, instead, the value of the first row is "sell", do this:

```
dir

sell
buy 
sell
buy
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please provide an honest attempt at solving this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dir': ['buy']*4})
if df.loc[0, 'dir'] == 'buy':
    df.loc[df.index % 2 != 0, 'dir'] = 'sell'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dir
0   buy
1  sell
2   buy
3  sell
```

DataFrame 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dir': ['sell']*4})    
if df.loc[0, 'dir'] == 'sell':
    df.loc[df.index % 2 != 0, 'dir'] = 'buy'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dir
0  sell
1   buy
2  sell
3   buy
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be more elegant solutions but as the simplest one I would create two new columns and add the one based on `numpy.where()`.

```
li = ['sell','buy','buy','buy','buy']
df = pandas.DataFrame(li, columns=['dir'])
new_column1 = ['sell' if i % 2 == 0 else 'buy' for i in range(len(li))]
new_column2 = ['sell' if i % 2 != 0 else 'buy' for i in range(len(li))]


print(new_column1)
print(new_column2)


df['dir'] = np.where(df['dir'].iloc[0] == "buy", new_column2, new_column1)
```